# file loads differently from browser to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a d3.js file which I am using in one of my applications.

**Issue :** When I use firefox as my browser it loads fine.
But When I use chrome, the "January" month shifts down and february is interchanged as it goes down to extreme left bottom corner.

Please refer to the above fiddle link.Running it on multiple browsers will hint at the issue.

Why is this happening from browser to browser.**Is there a permanent solution,such that it supports all the browsers?**

javascript of the that is already included in the fiddle above :

```js
'use strict';

var dataset = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

// let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'];
let colors = ['#67001f', '#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#e0e0e0', '#bababa', '#878787', '#4d4d4d', '#1a1a1a', 'white', 'white'];
var months = ['January - 2016', 'February - 2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];
var dataWeeks = ["Week 1: 32<br>Week 2: 54<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 12", "Week 5: 22<br>Week 6: 14<br>Week 7: 12<br>Week 8: 03<br>Week 9:44", "Week 10: 14<br>Week 11: 11<br>Week 12: 23<br>Week 13:20 <br>Quarter 1 :25", "Week 14: 53<br>Week 15: 16<br>Week 16: 11 <br>Week 17:33", "Week 18: 52<br>Week 19: 22<br>Week 20: 12 <br>Week 21 :09 <br>Week 22:34", "Week 23: 59<br>Week 24: 87 <br>Week 25:36<br>Week 26:78<br>Quarter 2 :56<br>Half Yearly 1 :98", "Week 27: 69<br>Week 28: 33<br>Week 29: 11<br>Week 30: 65", "Week 31: 69<br>Week 32: 33<br>Week 33: 99<br>Week 34: 66<br>Week 35: 19", "Week 36: 84<br>Week 37: 16<br>Week 38: 66<br>Week 39: 11<br>Quarter 3 : 77", "Week 40: 86<br>Week 41: 21<br>Week 42: 52<br>Week 43: 12<br>Week 44: 37", "Week 45: 90<br>Week 46: 69<br>Week 47: 19<br>Week 48: 17", "Week 49:33 <br>Week 50:09 <br>Week 51:44 <br>Week 52 : 89<br>Quarter 4 :66<br>Half Yearly 2:99"];

var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
  height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
  minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  initialAnimDelay = 300,
  arcAnimDelay = 150,
  arcAnimDur = 3000,
  secDur = 1000,
  secIndividualdelay = 150;

var radius = undefined;

// calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
if (minOfWH > 200) {
  radius = 200;
} else {
  radius = minOfWH;
}

// append svg
var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
  'width': width,
  'height': height,
  'class': 'pieChart'
}).append('g');

svg.attr({
  'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
});

// for drawing slices
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

// for labels and polylines
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

// d3 color generator
// let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d;
});

var draw = function draw() {

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

  // define slice
  var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(dataset).selectAll('path').data(pie);
  slice.enter().append('path').attr({
    'fill': function fill(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    },
    'd': arc,
    'stroke-width': '25px'
  }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
  }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
  }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

  slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

  var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  };

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(dataset));

  text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).text(function(d, i) {
    return months[i];
  }).attr('transform', function(d) {
    // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    // define left and right alignment of text labels
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
  }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);

  text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.html(dataWeeks[i])
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 14 + 'px')
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  });


  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(dataset));

  polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
  }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
  });
};

draw();

var button = document.querySelector('button');

var replay = function replay() {

  d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

  setTimeout(draw, 800);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable sorting by adding `sort(null)`:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
   return d;
}).sort(null); // disable sorting
```

By default D3 is sorting by value which leads to the random result in your case.

See the [documentation for D3 3.x here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pie-Layout.md):

> **pie.sort([comparator])**
>
> If comparator is specified, sets the sort order of data for the layout
>   using the specified comparator function. Pass null to disable sorting.
>   If comparator is not specified, returns the current sort order. **The
>   sort order defaults to descending value**.